# In Mathematica/Wolfram language, is there any way to check that an expression evaluated?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have a function:

```
Foo[x_] := If[x==2, Print@"Two", Print@"No"]
```

Then if I write the following:

```
Foo[oops]; Foo[5]
```

Where `oops` is a misspelled name for a global variable, the result is that the call to `Foo[oops]` just falls through rather than giving an error. I know why this is - because it creates a symbolic expression that, since it is not evaluated, does not do anything - but it's very awkward for procedural programming. Is there any way to specify that a function or expression must be completely evaluated and to give an error or return an appropriate value if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require a numeric argument do something like this:

```
foo[x_?NumericQ] := whatever
foo[x_] := Print["Error"]
```

Be sure to `Clear` your original definition before defining this way.

In your example you could alternately work with the three argument form of `If`